# R plot time series data: Extremely Short time laps

Tags: r, time-series

I have the following data frame. The gaps between time slots are different, sometimes small, sometimes large:

```
history <- structure(list(timestamp = structure(1:13, .Label = c("2006-06-11 04:43:56",
"2006-06-11 04:47:24", "2006-06-11 04:47:54", "2006-06-11 04:49:37",
"2006-06-11 04:52:12", "2006-06-11 04:58:22", "2006-06-11 05:01:11",
"2006-06-11 05:06:56", "2006-06-11 05:14:35", "2006-06-11 05:21:44",
"2006-08-21 19:55:50", "2006-08-21 19:56:31", "2007-11-22 22:09:17"
), class = "factor"), page_length = c(1753, 146, 2401, 461, 113,
1248, 1268, 720, 1290, 436, 531, 502, 746)), .Names = c("timestamp",
"page_length"), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")

history
#             timestamp page_length
#1  2006-06-11 04:43:56        1753
#2  2006-06-11 04:47:24         146
#3  2006-06-11 04:47:54        2401
#4  2006-06-11 04:49:37         461
#5  2006-06-11 04:52:12         113
#6  2006-06-11 04:58:22        1248
#7  2006-06-11 05:01:11        1268
#8  2006-06-11 05:06:56         720
#9  2006-06-11 05:14:35        1290
#10 2006-06-11 05:21:44         436
#11 2006-08-21 19:55:50         531
#12 2006-08-21 19:56:31         502
#13 2007-11-22 22:09:17         746
```

but the issue that I am having is that when I use the following method to plot I don't get a clear separation between time.

```
plot(as.POSIXlt(history$timestamp,format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), 
     log(history$page_length), xlab= "Months", ylab= "log page Length", type='l', col='red')
```

As you see in the plot I want to get a good separation between short timespans
[image]

Comment: Actually, this question is much more appropriate for StackOverflow because it is about programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use **[xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts)** for time series, and I use **[quantmod](http://cran.r-project.org/package=quantmod)** for producing the type of chart that (I think) you want.  (I also avoid `POSIXlt` when possible because it is slower and uses more memory than `POSIXct`)

```
library(quantmod)
x <- xts(history[, 2], as.POSIXct(history[, 1]))
chartSeries(log(x), theme="white")
```

[image]

There's also `chart_Series`, but, currently, it is undocumented and less developed than `chartSeries`.

Alternatively, you can use xts's `axTicksByTime` function directly, but the x-axis won't be as nicely formatted.

```
plot(head(axTicksByTime(x), -1), log(x), type="l", col="red")
```

Answer (score 0):

`type='l'` means type of the plot is line. So it shows you a line... You probably want `type = 'p'`, that is points.

See more info [here](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/plot.html) and look at some R plotting tutorials, there is more than enough of them around.